# Mysql selecting unique values

Tags: mysql, select, count

I am really stuck with an sql query... I hope someone can help shed some light for me.

Here is what my table looks like

```
mysql> show fields from france_data;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email    | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| quality  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state    | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| owner    | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the catch, I have duplicate data in my table, I would like to pull out all data from this table, non-duplicated based on the email.

I ran a simple count like this:

```
mysql> select count(*) from france_data;
```

and this is the result set:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2405259 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now I tried to run a count like this:

```
mysql> select count(*) from france_data group by email;
```

Just to see how many unique records I have. Unfortunately this times out.

Does any one know how I can do a count of unique rows and select of the same type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) FROM france_data
```

Comment: Thats great!! The count works :) but now I have tried the same query without COUNT(). I am not sure if it just takes a long time to run or if it is hanging and wont work. Is this how I do the select? `SELECT DISTINCT email FROM france_data;`

Comment: I think you could split query more than 1 statement with LIMIT command
[link](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Comment: Lets say I use `Limit 0,500` should this result in 500 rows being assed, then only distinct values being returned, effectively resulting in me having a return of less than 500 rows?

Comment: ok, its now working :) good start to a good day for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking at unique rows based on email, a simple

```
select count(distinct email) from france_data
```

should do the trick.

If you're also looking to see each email's duplicate count, try this:

```
select email, count(*) as cnt from france_data group by email order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: The count distinct is working for me, I dont need to know how many times its duplicated though, but I do need to output a result table that displays all fields with the email fields being unique.

Comment: Wow, that second query is exactly what I was looking for! Somehow I’d never digested how `group by` behaves. Thank you very much @Nikhil!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

SELECT count(DISTINCT email) FROM france_data ORDER BY email;